# Hide the value of a column in a view

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, schema

I'm trying to hide a date value in a column until it is needed, is there a way to hide a field's value in a view?

```
<Field ID="{6BA16C6C-79E0-4F4D-B2A7-81FF2FC2B801}" Name="len_cp_SignedIn_FullTime"
StaticName="len_cp_SignedIn_FullTime"
DisplayName="Signed In Time">
<Default>[Today]</Default>
</Field>
```

This is the value of the field, in my view it is displaying [Today] for this column, but I don't need to see the value until something else is triggered on the site, is there a way to hide this until then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store it in field's attribute

`<Field ID="{6BA16C6C-79E0-4F4D-B2A7-81FF2FC2B801}" Name="len_cp_SignedIn_FullTime"
StaticName="len_cp_SignedIn_FullTime"
DisplayName="Signed In Time" 
Default="[Today]">
</Field>`

And then use the attribute  client-side when needed

Comment: There's no attribute for Default in the tag.

Comment: @RyanJ If you found the solution to your problem you should post it here. It may help someone else in the future.